# Php increment Select query one by one

Tags: php, sql, database

In the code given below i am calling get.php?id=inc every time button is clicked Using Ajax.
I want that when every time this get.php is called select query fetch next record in table.

JavaScript File:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?id=inc",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

get.php File:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['nextq'])){ //nextq the name of button
$idd= $_GET['id'];
include 'library/php/connect.php';
$q = "SELECT * from hp_questions where id=$idd";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
echo 
$row['question'];      
}
?>
```

Comment: sounds like pagination

Comment: what should i do ? @Fred-ii-

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Please give me solution

Comment: Google "ajax pagination php" you'll find a whole bunch of results. Here's the first one that popped up http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php